# converting xml to xml using xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

Hi I have one xml I need to convert that xml to another xml using xsl

my XML looks like

```
<Information>
    <ShipmentType>
        <shipmentType>A</shipmentType>
    </ShipmentType>
    <ShipmentRouting>
        <airportCityCodeOrigin>AAA</airportCityCodeOrigin>
        <airportCityCodeDestination>BBB</airportCityCodeDestination>
    </ShipmentRouting>
    <EarliestDepartureDateTime>
        <dayOfMonth>00</dayOfMonth>
        <month>OCT</month>
    </EarliestDepartureDateTime>
</Information>
```

It should be converted into this format:

```
<ECIDRA-INP>
   <DRA-INP>
      <OPTION>
         <ORIGIN>
            <STATION>AAA</STATION>
         </ORIGIN>
         <DEST>
            <STATION>BBB</STATION>
         </DEST>
      </OPTION>
   </DRA-INP>
</ECIDRA-INP>
```

I need only the value of `<airportCityCodeOrigin>` and `<airportCityCodeDestination>` but I am getting all the tags values.

Below is the XSL that I wrote:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/Information">
        <ECIDRA-INP>
            <DRA-INP>
                <OPTION>
                    <ORIGIN>
                        <STATION>
                            <xsl:value-of select="./ShipmentRouting/airportCodeofDeparture"></xsl:value-of>
                        </STATION>
                    </ORIGIN>
                    <DEST>
                        <STATION>
                            <xsl:value-of select="./ShipmentRouting/airportCodeofArrival"></xsl:value-of>
                        </STATION>
                    </DEST>
                </OPTION>
            </DRA-INP>
        </ECIDRA-INP>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: "my XML looks like"..; you mean XML without angle brackets? ;-) Show us real XML (and real XSLT), please.

Comment: Please edit your question and start every XML code line with four spaces; that way your XML tags won't disappear. http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation of the issue and for its easy correction. :)

Answer (score 0):

Are A AAA BBB 00 OCT the data or the names of the tags? This is important, as the manner of pruning data is different from "pruning" tags.

To create a new XML that only contains 2 tag names out of 5, you merely write the output XML as you would like it and then introduce the transformation bits to pull the data. If you are aiming at specific data, and want to do it with XML (as XSLT), then you need to write XPath to select out the proper nodes. Your other option is to use a language where you have full Regex capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

**The problem with your code is that it uses non-existent element names, such as `airportCodeofDeparture` and `airportCodeofArrival`**.

Just correct to:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/Information">
      <ECIDRA-INP>
        <DRA-INP>
          <OPTION>
            <ORIGIN>
              <STATION>
            <xsl:value-of select=
                   "ShipmentRouting/airportCityCodeOrigin"/>
          </STATION>
            </ORIGIN>
            <DEST>
              <STATION>
                <xsl:value-of select=
                    "ShipmentRouting/airportCityCodeDestination"/>
              </STATION>
            </DEST>
         </OPTION>
        </DRA-INP>
      </ECIDRA-INP>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied to the provided XML document**:

```
<Information>
    <ShipmentType>
        <shipmentType>A</shipmentType>
    </ShipmentType>
    <ShipmentRouting>
        <airportCityCodeOrigin>AAA</airportCityCodeOrigin>
        <airportCityCodeDestination>BBB</airportCityCodeDestination>
    </ShipmentRouting>
    <EarliestDepartureDateTime>
        <dayOfMonth>00</dayOfMonth>
        <month>OCT</month>
    </EarliestDepartureDateTime>
</Information>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<ECIDRA-INP>
   <DRA-INP>
      <OPTION>
         <ORIGIN>
            <STATION>AAA</STATION>
         </ORIGIN>
         <DEST>
            <STATION>BBB</STATION>
         </DEST>
      </OPTION>
   </DRA-INP>
</ECIDRA-INP>
```